# Calling RESTful WCF Operation with DataContract object

Tags: wcf, datacontract

I have the following OperationContract in my ServiceContract:

```
[WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate="books")]
[OperationContract]
void AddBookToInventory(BookTitle aBook);
```

BookTitle is a DataContract object:

```
[DataContract(Namespace="http://someurl.com/books")]
public class BookTitle
{
    string title = "";
    string author = "";
    string isbn = "";
    decimal price = 0.00m;


    [DataMember]
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Author
    {
        get { return author; }
        set { author = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Isbn
    {
        get { return isbn; }
        set { isbn = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public decimal Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value; }
    }

}
```

How do I call the AddBookToInventory operation using XML from a .NET client in c# or vb?

Answer (score 0):

you must write `POST` [webrequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) to url http://yourServiceName.svc/books